# Wireless Sensor to Internet

Tags: wireless, wifi, zigbee, system-on-chip, tcp-ip

Looking for a low cost implementation to post ambient temperature readings from a sensor to servers via a COTS router.

1) Have a temperature sensor connected to a micro controller which sends data via a Wifi Module with a TCP/IP Stack to servers
2) Have a temperature sensor communicated via Zigbee to a coordinator that is plugged into a router and communicates with the servers.

Would like to keep the cost of the solution below $20. Another constraint is the battery life. Wifi modules with TCP/IP consume more power and cost more.

What particular devices/chips/microcontrollers would you recommend to solve my data communication problem and fit within my budget?

Comment: very close to this question I asked [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25196/wifi-module-with-mcu-on-one-board)

Comment: Elaborate more on the power requirements.  Is this device unable to be powered by a wall-wart, etc?  Since it's wireless, how far away will the device be placed from the router?  Is it going to be outdoors or indoors?

Comment: I wrote up a blog entry on getting from an analog sensor to the internet (Pachube) via Ethernet (with a Nanode) over an inexpensive, low power RF link (Wicked Node / Receiver Shield) a while ago: http://blog.wickeddevice.com/?p=244... but under $20 is a tall order.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Digi Xbee on the sensor to pass the information to a Connectport X2, which has either ethernet or wifi. The Xbee is a Zigbee radio with a simple serial interface. The X2 has a Zigbee radio and an IP connection and runs python.

There are several tutorials on how to get one working. [This one](http://community.thingspeak.com/tutorials/wireless/connecting-xbee-wireless-networks-to-thingspeak-via-the-connectport-x2-running-xig/) looks like a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not in a hurry, you can wait for the new Electric Imp kits. The developer kits should be coming out soon. (Says "end of June, 2012" on the website).

http://electricimp.com/docs/gettingstarted/devkits/

---

The **Hannah: The hobbyist board** even has the temperature sensor built in.

Comment: Updated link http://electricimp.com/docs/gettingstarted/devkits/

Answer (score 0):

Pachube / Cosm, which is now called [Xively](https://xively.com), is a service/platform/API for posting sensor data to the web. If you click on Support/API and then go to hardware, they have a lot of information on the various hardware that is compatible with their service. And they have libraries for controllers like the Arduino.