# Cheapest solution to get data from a temperature sensor (thermistor for example) to the Internet

Tags: ethernet, bluetooth, wifi, zigbee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless Sensor to Internet](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33342/wireless-sensor-to-internet)

Looking to explore the cheapest solution to get data from a temperature sensor to the internet. Assume you have access to a COTS router connected to the internet.

1) Wifi: A wifi module which talks directly to the router. A cheap microcontroller takes data from the sensor and sends via serial to wifi module, to the internet.
2) PAN: A dongle connects directly into the RJ-45 for a router and communicates with internet. It has a PAN (bluetooth, zigbee, etc) with another box which has the temperature sensor. The microcontroller on this box uses the PAN to send data to the dongle which sends it to the Internet.

I know both of these options are possible. Which is the cheaper option? I know wifi modules are pretty expensive.

Also, do you have recommendations of which particular chips I can use for the Wifi, Bluetooth/Zigbee and RJ-45 ethernet communications?

Comment: Why not interact with all the people who tried to answer you the first time?  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33342/wireless-sensor-to-internet

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into using a WIFI module to communicate to the internet, and they are costly.  the cheapest wifi module I could find was around $50(arduino wifi shield) if you want just the wifi chip it is still $30.  I think you can get a your ethernet dongle for around 25/30.

I think your best best would be to use a wiznet chip that has an ADC on the chip.  then use the wiznet to do a simple temperature read on one of the ADC, and send it over the ethernet.  I think the wiznet chips are around 30ish to 40ish, but you would only need an thermistor with it.